# Adding multiple rows with the same name pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a quick question.
If I have multiple rows with the same NAME but different quantities is there a pandas function to just add them?

```
NAME     QTY
A         2
A         5

A         6

A total = 13?
```

Comment: look into groupby

Comment: why did I get downvote?

Comment: I was not the one to downvote but this is a simple case of df.groupby('NAME').sum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html).  if your data frame is named `df`:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['NAME'],values=['QTY'],aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: This worked with a little Change
df = oo.pivot_table(values='QTY',index='NAME',aggfunc='sum')
df

Comment: @ifapps Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do it. But in simple terms it is grouping & aggregation.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum
df.groupBy('NAME').agg(sum('QTY')).show()
```